# F# | Array.map & Array.filter in one step (single function)

Tags: f#

Having this example:

```ml
open FSharp.Data

let jsonStirng = @"[ 
    {""red"": 100, ""green"": 100, ""blue"": 100, ""alpha"": 1.0 },
    {""red"": 100, ""green"": 100, ""blue"": 100, ""alpha"": 0.5 },
    ]"

let getSolidColors jsonString =
    let getColor item = 
        if (item:JsonValue).["alpha"].AsDecimal() < 1m
        then Some( {R=item.["red"].AsInteger(); G=item.["green"].AsInteger(); B=item.["blue"].AsInteger()} )
        else None

    JsonValue.Parse(jsonString).AsArray() 
    |> Array.map getColor 
    |> Array.filter (fun x -> x.IsSome)
    |> Array.map (fun x -> x.Value)
```

Is it possible to have a single function that makes the map & filter funtion in a single call?
Kind of `Array.mapfilter` (it's not *reduce* because I don't have an accumulator, or maybe it's the solution?!)

Or, there is an alternative implementation (apart from a *for* loop) to avoid using an intermediate *Option* and 3 Array function calls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you can do:

```
JsonValue.Parse(jsonString).AsArray() 
|> Array.choose getColor
```